# Add newly created attribute to existing product in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-attribute

I have created a new attribute for products, but i am having around 1000 of product. The thing is i cannot edit each one and add the attribute to it. Is there any way i could add this attribute to all of this product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1:**(if you want same value for all products)

Follow the below steps:

- Goto Catalog -> Products
- Select All products
- Now select Update attributes from action dropdown then submit
- Update your newly added attribute with some value and save.

**Method 2:**(if you want set different values for each products)

Create a csv with column sku and newly added attribute. Now import that csv from admin.

- Goto System -> Import
- Select **Products** as Entity type
- Select Add/Update as Import Behaviour
- Browse your csv and click on Check Data
- After that you can import those data by click on Import